# Does Querydsl not support rand()?

Tags: java, querydsl

I want to make SQL look like:

```
select b from Book b order by rand()
```

how convert that query to Querydsl query?

Is it not supported by Querydsl? 
If you know the way to support this query, please answer it..;

thank you.

Comment: What is `rand`? Over which RDBMS are you trying to execute this?

Comment: rand() method is RDBMS function. I used it with mysql.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Querydsl SQL supports it via

```
NumberExpression.random()
```

So your query could be expressed like this

```
query.from(b)
    .orderBy(NumberExpression.random().asc())
    .list(b);
```

I am not sure how well it is supported for JPQL, it doesn't seem to be in the standard.

Comment: Timo. It occurs the error that is "ERROR: FUNCTION bookstore_web.random does not exist". My environment is QueryDSL 3.1 and Hibernate 4.1.10.Final.

Comment: It's supported for Querydsl SQL, I am not aware of JPQL supporting it, you asked for SQL.

Comment: @xyzlast Please let me know if you find out how random is supported in JPQL. I also update my answer, to be more clear.

Comment: I cannot find out how random is supported in JPQL. I think it's not possible now. So I use it with Hibernate HQL. look like this. 
        Session session = (Session) getEntityManager().getDelegate();
        return (List<Book>) session.createQuery("from Book order by rand()").list();

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I think QueryDSL is the great solution. :)

Comment: Hibernate is very permissive with unknown functions and passes them through, but this is not offical JPQL and also the rand() form is not universally supported in SQL, for e.g. PostgreSQL it's random(), but I will see if this can be somehow fixed in Querydsl JPA

Answer (score 2):

A addition to Timo's answer.

If you use mysql you will get the error "ERROR: FUNCTION schema.random does not exist", this is because mysql has a RAND function instead of a RANDOM function. To fix this you can either add the random function in sql, like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS RANDOM;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION RANDOM () 
RETURNS DECIMAL(15,15)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE dist DECIMAL(15,15);
  SET dist = RAND();
  RETURN dist;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Or fix the random function to use rand with:

```
public class MySQLJPATemplates extends JPQLTemplates {

    public static final MySQLJPATemplates DEFAULT = new MySQLJPATemplates();

    public MySQLJPATemplates() {
        this(DEFAULT_ESCAPE);
        add(Ops.MathOps.RANDOM, "rand()");
        add(Ops.MathOps.RANDOM2, "rand({0})");
    }

    public MySQLJPATemplates(char escape) {
        super(escape);
    }
}
```

And use the template as follows:

```
JPAQuery<Route> query = new JPAQuery<Route>(em, MySQLJPATemplates.DEFAULT);
query.from(b)
    .orderBy(NumberExpression.random().asc())
    .list(b);
```